# Time report: deleting from table

Tags: sql, report, reporting, sql-delete

Is there a way to update the table in the link below to remove the entries that have missing hours in one id but not another?

There are several instances where a user stopped using one id and started using another.

I need to see Smith's time in both 123 and 456 while excluding lines that have missing hours when there are already hours inputted into the week in another id.

[See table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99Ygp.png)

[See desired resulting table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvl87.png)

Comment: I added a second link. Ideally the week start and end should transition from one id to the next without duplicating the weeks.

Comment: I feel like there's a bit of this I'm not clear on, but can you tell me if/why `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE hours > 0` wouldn't work? I feel like there may be an exception in your case where this wouldn't return the desired resultset, but it's not inherently clear to me from your current question/example.

Comment: The report must be able to see weeks where an employee has not entered hours (eg. smith did not input any time using 123 or 456). All weeks need to be seen,

Comment: Ah, I see. What i've done in the past for things like this is create a new table called `weeks`, and write a loop to populate it with every week for the next 20 years. I'd then do a `JOIN` on that table to ensure I get every week, regardless of whether there's data for it or not. The reason I'd suggest this as opposed to doing some witty loop in the query itself is simply efficiency. I find it better to do the loop once and populate the table, than to do it each and every time you want to run this query. Hopefully this is at least a nudge in the right direction.